# Coerce HCPC object to hclust to use library(ape)

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, coercion

I am currently performing hierarchical cluster. I opted to use `FactoMineR` due to its nice data exploration pipeline: data->MFA->HCPC.

```
data("wine")
names(wine)
res<-MFA(wine,group = c(2,5,3,10,9,2),type=c("n",rep("s",5)),
         ncp=5,name.group = c("orig","olf","vis","olfag","gust","ens"),
         num.group.sup = c(1,6))

res.hcpc<-HCPC(res, nb.clust=0, consol=F, iter.max=10, min=3, 
           max=NULL, metric="euclidean", method="ward", order=TRUE,
           graph.scale="sqrt-inertia", nb.par=5, graph=TRUE, proba=0.05, 
           cluster.CA="rows",kk=Inf)

#Now for some nice plots
plot(res.hcpc,draw.tree = T,choice = "tree")
plot(res.hcpc,draw.tree = T,choice = "bar")
```

These are more than sufficient when wanting to extract answers, but I am looking to present these trees. i.e I want them a bit spruced up through `library(ape)` - [examples](https://rpubs.com/gaston/dendrograms)

The problem is that these functions require a `hclust` object. One option I had was to use the `MFA` results and use an `hclust` function as: `res.hc<-hclust(dist(res$global.pca$ind$coord),method = "ward.D2")` to build a `hclust` object.

This does work, however I find the information that `HCPC` gives is much more informative (and answers differ from hclust). Thus I want to work with the `HCPC` object and not `hclust`, but still be able to use the functions in `library(ape)`. **Any idea how one would coerce `HCPC` to `hclust`**?

Comment: the `value` section in `?hclust` tells you exactly what makes an hclust object, so you just need to fill in the holes, eg, `h2 <- structure(list(merge = matrix(-c(1,3,2,-1), 2), height = c(0, 10), order = 1:3, labels = 1:3, dist.method = 'euclidean', call = quote(hclust(dist, method = "ave"))), class = 'hclust'); plot(h2)`

Comment: @rawr, I have had a look at the structure of the `hclust`. I am going to start and figure out how I could make this work. Being from a non-programming background, I was hoping someone with a better R development pedigree would provide a workable function which could be included into the `FactoMineR` package. i.e correct structure and usage as needed by cran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**for library(ape)**

```
hcpcTree<-res.hcpc$call$t$tree
apeTree<-as.phylo(hcpcTree)
```

**for library(stats)**

```
dendextendTree<-as.phylo.dendrogram(hcpcTree)
```